# C#/WCF pass in parameter a file path

Tags: c#, wcf, azure

I'm currently working on a web service with C#, WCF and azure storage. I need to make a upload method but I have a problem with the path of files to upload. Indeed I can't pass in parameter the path file, It's always return null in the method how can I deal with that ? Here the code :

```
public void uploadFiles(string path, string ContainerName)
{
    // Connect to the storage account's blob endpoint 
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

    // Create the blob storage container 
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(ContainerName);
    container.CreateIfNotExists();

    // Create the blob in the container 
    CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("name");

    using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path))
    {
        blob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
    }
}
```

The string path is directly null so I can't add @.

Comment: what is the value of `path` in your case..? can you show us..?

Comment: if `path` is null, check place, where you call `uploadFiles(...) `

Comment: Please don't "thanks per advance" and *definitely please* stop adding a signature at the bottom.  We don't do that here.  Besides, **your name and avatar are already at the bottom of your post**.  For more info, check out [meta].

Comment: Don't use WCF to transfer files. Place the file binary in accessible storage: local disk, azure storage, amazon S3, etc and pass around information that allows you to retrieve the file from the location. While WCF is capable of passing files it is an extremely poor choice to use to do so. For physically moving the file samba/ftp are optimal, but in all likelihood HTTP will end up being used. For the complexities of using a true file protocol I would only do it for uploads of 500MB or more.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a path from a remote client to your service.  The path will be to a file on the client.  You cannot open that path on your server.

To upload a file, you are going to have to pass the actual file data.

Comment: And transfering files over WCF is problematic at best or comical at worst.